# CalendarView Meizu on FlymeOS

Tags: android, view, calendarview

I make app with calendar.
I use simple CalendarView.

```
<CalendarView
android:id="@+id/calendarView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

On Emulator, all ok.
But on my phone, Meizu Pro 5 standard view replaced with Calendar from Meizu.

So my question, how can i keep standard calendar view like on Emulator with AOSP.
[Emulator view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gau4m.png)
[Meizu view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yV1T.png)

Comment: Also this be no problem if Meizu Calendar view will not show 3 month at same time.